# Convert HashMap of integers into unique integer array?

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I take the information stored in a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` and create unique arrays of values. I do not need them in reverse order or any other ordering.

For example, assuming I have:

```
Key      Value
---      ---------
1        {1, 2, 3}
2        {10, 11}
3        {29}
```

How can I turn this into the following:

```
{1, 10, 29}
{1, 11, 29}
{2, 10, 29}
{2, 11, 29}
{3, 10, 29}
{3, 11, 29}
```

Ive tried a variety of loops. I also pondered tail end recursion however it still has me stumped. I would appreciate your guidance so I may solve this.

What my goal is: The key value is the primary key for an attribute. Each attribute has options which are contained in the value. I would like to restructure the information so it fits the format shown.

Comment: This is what `Set` implementations are for.

Comment: Jarrod, thanks for the response. I will start researching Set implementations.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I don't think a `Set` is a specific solution here. The title is rather irrelevant to the problem: he's looking for all permutations that hold one value from each key.

Comment: You are asking for how to generate the *cartesian product*.  There are countless duplicates here on SO.

Comment: Oli, after researching what a cartesian product is, I agree with duplicate. Thanks for hinting at solution.